# SQL Query Select four entries from three tables if two entries are equal

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have three different tables:

```
1. Table Business
ID, Name, fk_Input, fk_Output
    
2. Table Input
Id, FK_Business_id, Name

3.
Id, FK_Business_id, Name
```

I created a Database Example on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de4efa).

Now just want to check which Business has the same output.name like some other Business has as Input.name and show as result both Business names and which Resource can be shared.

So an example for better understanding

```
1. Table Business
ID, Name, fk_Input, fk_Output

1, AdventureA, 1,1
2, BuinsnessB, 2,2
3, CompanyC,   3,3

2.Table Input
Id, FK_Business_id, Name
1, 1(AdventureA),coal
2, 1(AdventureA),Air
3, 2(BusinessB) ,Cooper
4, 2(BusinessB) ,Power
5, 3(CompanyC)  ,Wood

3.Table Output
Id, FK_Business_id, Name
1, 1(AdventureA), Power
2, 2(BusinessB) , Cooperbar     
3, 3(CompanyC)  , Power
```

Result should be:

```
AdventureA has Power for BusinessB
CompanyC   has Power for BusinessB
```

or in other words like this

```
BusinessnameOutput, BusinessnameInput, NameInput, NameOutput
```

I have tried

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Business.Name, Output.Name, Input.Name FROM Business, Input, Output 
WHERE Output.Name = Input.Name
```

But results in to much rows with no sense

also tried

```sql
SELECT Business.Name, Input.Name, Output.Name 
FROM Unternehmen 
INNER JOIN Input ON Input.FK_Business_id,   = Business.ID 
INNER JOIN Output ON Output.FK_Business_id = Business.ID
WHERE Input.Name = Output.Name
```

but results in no entries.

Query with almost the right result was

```sql
SELECT Business.Name, Input.Name, Output.Name FROM Business,Input, Output WHERE Input.Name = Output.Name GROUP BY Input.RessourceName
```

But it shows just one Businessname instead of both businessnames which has the same output as an input.

Got no clue how I can solve that dilemma? Anyone got an idea, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inner join  and proper condition for join

```
select distinct concat( Business.Name, ' has ',  Output.Name, ' for ', Business2.name) 
from Business 
inner join Output on Business.fk_Output = Output.id
inner join Input on Input.name = Output.name
inner join Business as Business2 on Input.fk_business_id = Business2.id ;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de4efa/6

Comment: I think that works. Thank you very much. I got one entrie query wont show but i think there would be a mistake on the database. I tested your querie with a new example i insert to the Database and it shows the result like i want. Thank you againt thats great. :)